# Contact form 7 CORS

Tags: wordpress, cors, contact-form-7

I have a question about how contact form 7 works.

**Scenario**

**mainsite.com**
**clone.mainsite.com**

I need to post from **mainsite.com** to **clone.mainsite.com**, I can edit the form action through a hook, no problem there, that works.

When I send the form chrome is telling me I have a 200 success (preflight I'm assuming)0to **clone.mainsite.com** and the email *sends*, however the throbber gets stuck, because I'm receiving a CORs error from **clone.mainsite.com**. I enabled a plugin for WordPress that exposes ACCEPT-ORIGIN etc headers and it works when I navigate to them normally through a browser, however I cant get a reply from contact form 7 to work. If I just push through a call using basic custom Ajax I can get a message back no problem, no CORS errors.

I did notice contact form 7 sends Accept: application/json headers whereas my custom Ajax jsut sends the default */*.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that contact form 7 cuts off execution of the page before the headers plugin had a chance to add to the response.